# Use pipe number In Input text

Tags: angular

I use pipe number like this and works fine

```
{{ item.price | number }}
```

and I want to use this pipe In Input element text like this

```
<input type="text"  name="price" [ngModel]="price | number" (ngModelChange)="price=$event" >
```

I want to separate 3 number with a comma when I typing numbers in Input 
`222222222` to `222,222,222` In input text 
when I type number to show me this error:

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '2,22222 is not a number' for pipe
>   'DecimalPipe'

How can I solve this problem?
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nkh71w)

Comment: Why do you need the pipe?

Comment: @SirDieter I want to separate 3 number with a comma when I typing numbers in Input 
**222222222** to **222,222,222** In input text

Comment: @MohammadDaliri why you don't use **Directive** instead of **pipe** inside input control?????

Comment: @Sanoj_V I know It's made with Directive. But I want to know How can I use it by pipe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need create custom **pipe** for this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'numberPipe'
})
export class NumberPipePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(val) {
    val = this.format_number(val, '');
    return val;
  }

  format_number(number, prefix) {
    let thousand_separator = ',',
      decimal_separator = '.',
      regex = new RegExp('[^' + decimal_separator + '\\d]', 'g'),
      number_string = number.replace(regex, '').toString(),
      split = number_string.split(decimal_separator),
      rest = split[0].length % 3,
      result = split[0].substr(0, rest),
      thousands = split[0].substr(rest).match(/\d{3}/g);

    if (thousands) {
      let separator = rest ? thousand_separator : '';
      result += separator + thousands.join(thousand_separator);
    }
    result = split[1] != undefined ? result + decimal_separator + split[1] : result;
    return prefix == undefined ? result : (result ? prefix + result : '');
  };
}
```

here is working example :[Custom number pipe in input text](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwvwg7)

Comment: works like a charm, thanks. although you might need to convert number argument to a string like: `${number}`.replace()